# Where can I find a list of countries that allow visa-free entry for visa national cruise passengers?

Tags: online-resources, visa-free-entry, cruising

According to https://www.mfa.gov.tr/frequently-asked-questions.en.mfa foreigners who are travelling to Türkiye by cruises are allowed to enter Türkiye without visa for a maximum period of 72 hours, with the permission given by the local security authorities.

Is there a list anywhere of all countries that offer this kind of exemption to visa nationals?

Comment: I do not know in general. In past Russia (st. Peterburg) allowed visa free but only with cruise organized excursion. Oman gave a 24h visa (so technically a visa). In general cruise lines uses ports with easy/no visas (for targeted passengers), but so, it is also a negotiation with the country (you cannot arrive in a port with very small immigration infrastructure)